# Crontab doens't have effects

Tags: 18.04, cron, nginx, docker

I'm running the following command using crontab on Ubuntu 18.04. I can see inside /var/log/syslog that the command is performed, but it has not effect. The command is performed but it has not effect:

`0 23 * * * /usr/bin/docker run --rm -it --name certbot -v “/test/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt" -v “/test/var/lib/letsencrypt:/var/lib/letsencrypt" -v “/test/data/letsencr" -v “/test/var/log/letsencrypt:/var/log/letsencrypt" certbot/certbot renew --dry-run --webroot -w /data/letsencrypt --quiet && /usr/bin/docker kill --signal=HUP https-nginx`

Answer (score 2):

You are running the `docker` command with the `-it` options. This requires a terminal. A cron job doesn't have a terminal. Therefore your docker command cannot run from cron.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had not seen the error. That is working right now!